# I cannot get php to redirect with onclick()

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect, onclick

I have a button in php that will not redirect. Assume the page destination is correct, is anything else wrong with this line?

```
echo "<button id=\"create\" onclick=\"location.href('/team/teams.php?op=create');\">Create Team</button><br>";
```

thanks!

Comment: There are no any buttons in php.

Comment: Change to `location.href='/team/teams.php?op=create'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location.href` is not a function, it is a property so

```
onclick=\"location.href = '/team/teams.php?op=create';\"
```

In your case, there should be an error in your browser console saying `Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function`

Comment: that makes sense. thanks for the clear response! will check as correct once I am allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this?

```
echo "<button id=\"create\" onclick=\"location.href='/team/teams.php?op=create';\">Create Team</button><br>";
```

Comment: `javascript:`? What's that for? How about making some notes so that OP could learn something from you not just blindly copied your code (which is syntactically incorrect though).

Comment: Agreed. It serves no purpose. I'll take it out.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<button id='create' onclick='window.location=\"/team/teams.php?op=create\";'>Create</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript syntax is:

```
location.href = 'url_to_go';
```

So just delete the bracket and give an equal sign after 'location.href'
Here is the code look like:

```
echo "<button id=\"create\" onclick=\"location.href = '/team/teams.php?op=create';\">Create Team</button><br>";
```